# how to easily find a class instance in a list with a given class attribute?

Tags: python, reference, class-attributes

I'm a newbie. I am wondering if there is a way to easily find an instance of a class in a list with a given attribute. (Python)

basically the set up is as follows:

```
class idk:
    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

x = idk("x", 2)
y = idk("y", 3)
a = [x, y]
```

So a is a list with two instances of the class idk. How do I easily find the elements of a with name "x"?

I am looking for something like:

```
a["x"] returning x
```

or

```
b = [t in a, t.name == "x"] returning [x]
```

Comment: iterate through the list and check, is generally how you do it.

Comment: that's what I've been doing, but i'd like an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter`:

```
b = list(filter(lambda elem: elem.name == 'x', a))
```

but your list comprehension could work just fine as well.